# JQuery, Accordion & multiple menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using combination of the Wayfinder and Accordion menu to drive behaviour of the left column menu. This menu has two levels, i.e.:

```
<ul class="accordion">:
Menu 1
    Sub-menu 1.1
    Sub-menu 1.2    
    Sub-menu 1.3
Menu 2
    Sub-menu 2.1
    Sub-menu 2.2    
Menu 3
    Sub-menu 3.1
    Sub-menu 3.2    
Menu 4
    Sub-menu 4.1
    Sub-menu 4.2
```

There is also the following header menu:

```
<ul class="nav"> (no sub-menus):
Menu 2
Menu 3
```

The below code handles the left column menu ("accordion" class). I would like extend the code, so clicking on 'Menu 2' from the header menu ("nav" class) would have the very same effect as clicking on the 'Menu 2' ("accordion" class). I.e. clicking on the 'Menu 2' ("nav" class) would expand 'Menu 2' with "accordion" class.

Hers is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Store variables

        var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
            accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu'),
            nav_head = $('.nav > li > a');

        // Open the first tab on load

        accordion_head.eq(2).addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');         

        // Click function

        accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {

            // Disable header links

            event.preventDefault();

            // Show and hide the tabs on click

            if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
                accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
                $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
                accordion_head.removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                    accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
                    accordion_head.removeClass('active');
                }
        });
        nav_head.on('click', function(event) {

            // Disable header links

            event.preventDefault();

            // Show and hide the 'accordion tabs' on click on the 'nav tabs'

            <missing part>

        });
    });
</script>
```

Many thanks, LG

Comment: Please paste a complete but simplified HTML structure

Comment: elements withing the nav class are just a subset of elements from the accordion class.

Comment: believe me, sometimes when you paste the HTML we can suggest for a smarter solution instead of adding bugs to existing ones, cause from your question I can already see all you need is a couple of jQuery lines

Comment: @After a first look from an experienced eye of user experience, you should add an arrow symbol to every menus element that is expandable.

Comment: can you please clarify?

Comment: Would it be OK to remove the live demo? or remove the content?

Many thanks for the solution - it works beautifully :)

Comment: Sure, removed. Edited my answer to handle `hasClass` (/6/ demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the index of the clicked parent element as long they are in the same order (after the `home` button)

```
$(function(){

  var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
      accordion_sub  = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu'),
      nav_head       = $('.nav > li > a'); 

  accordion_head.not('.active').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!$(e.target).hasClass('active')){
          $('.accordion > li > a').removeClass('active');
          accordion_sub.slideUp();
          $(this).addClass('active').closest('li').find('.sub-menu').slideDown();    
     }
  });

  nav_head.on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.accordion > li').eq( $(this).closest('li').index() ).find('a').click();
  });

});
```